# Android white box testing

Tags: android, android-testing, white-box-testing, test-framework

I'm new android testing and for a while I'm using Android test framework to test my code(with the help of ProviderTestCase2, AndroidTestCase, activityinstrumentationtestcase2,etc) I want to know what are other frameworks available as opensource(**strictly white box**). I have come across **Robotium, Roboelectric, monkeyrunner, Calabash**). Which is used for Unit testing, testing android services? I got an overall idea that above frameworks used for black-box testing(correct me if I'm wrong). For white box testing **which is the best** test framework?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer robolectric because it can be easily run in PC, and it's quite helpful to test logicals in apps.

Robotium is for ui testing, and it's not worth spending a lot of time writing ui testing code in my opinion, since the ui/requirements are always changing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm also confused whether I can test android services like Mediaplayer servies, database as well. Apart from unit testing, is it worth using the framework for functional testing. I think Robotium is for Black-box testing. Need additional info on Roboelectric on functional testing as well.